# Page Reloads to Home Page After Opening Browser

Tags: templates

This is the strangest thing I've ever seen.  If I load my homepage (jonssite.com), then click on a sub link, (jonssite.com/about), it shows "jonssite.com/about" for a second, and then redirects to "jonssite.com/index.php".  If I try the link another time, it works.  This only happens when I first open the browser (any browser:  IE, Firefox, Chrome).  If I reload home without restarting the browswer, it works every time.

Comment: There isn't really much to go on here... and the site is currently just parked on godaddy.  Can you add some details?

Comment: It was the mobile detect plugin .  No problem.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and then accept it.  Also I can only remove my down vote if you edit your question...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the mobile detect plugin.  I removed it from the template and it worked correctly